# Derivative Product Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am thinking that my error in finding this derivative is an arithmetic error,but I keep getting it wrong. I have to use Product Rule to find the solution, and only product rule.

> $$f(x)=(-10x^2-7x^{\frac{2}{5}}+9)(2x^3+4)$$
>   For $f'(x)$ I got :
>   $$f'(x)=(-20x-\frac{35}{2}x^{\frac{-3}{5}})(2x^3+4)+(6x^2)(-10x^2-7x^{\frac{2}{5}}+9)$$
>   $$f'(x)=-100x^4-77x^{\frac{12}{5}}+54x^2-40x-70x^{\frac{-3}{5}}$$

I used Product Rule to get my answer but I can't find where I made my mistake. I graphed the derivative and my answer but they don't overlap completely.  What is the correct derivative of the function?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+(-10*x%5E2-7*x%5E(2%2F5)%2B9)*(2*x%5E3%2B4))

Comment: @Guest I've never used Wolfam Alpha before.Thanks its useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving $ 7x^{\frac{2}{5}} $ should give $ \frac{14}{5}x^{\frac{-3}{5}} $ and not $ \frac{35}{2}x^{\frac{-3}{5}} $. You multiplied with the reciprocal of 2/5 (or divided by 2/5) instead of multiplying the exponent.

Comment: Thanks that was the overall problem.